# Ruby `define_singleton_method` in `included` block vs `ClassMethods`

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Even Bar is included after Default module, it still can't override Default.foo.  Is it a way to do it?

```
module Default
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    define_singleton_method :foo do
      41
    end
  end
end
module Bar
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      42
    end
  end
end
class Foo
  include Default
  include Bar
end

Foo.foo
=> 41  #From Default.foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add some debug statements in your code, we will see that order of definition and inclusion of modules is something like below:

```
Defined => Default
Defined => Bar
Defined => ClassMethods
Included => Default
Included => Bar
41
```

**Since the event of inclusion of module `Default` happens after the module `Bar` has been defined, the defintion of `foo` that is in-effect is the one that is defined in the `included` block of module `Default`.**

*Code with debug statements added*

```
require "rails"

module Default
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts "Defined => Default"
  included do
    define_singleton_method :foo do
      41
    end
    puts "Included => Default"
  end
end
module Bar
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts "Defined => Bar"
  module ClassMethods
    puts "Defined => ClassMethods"
    def foo
      42
    end
  end
  included do
    puts "Included => Bar"
  end
end
class Foo
  include Default
  include Bar
end

p Foo.foo
```

---

**If you want the `foo` definition of `Bar` to be in effect, then, you can either define it too in `included` block of `Bar` as shown below:**

```
require "rails"

module Default
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts "Defined => Default"
  included do
    define_singleton_method :foo do
      41
    end
    puts "Included => Default"
  end
end
module Bar
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts "Defined => Bar"
  module ClassMethods
    puts "Defined => ClassMethods"
    def foo
      42
    end
  end
  included do
    puts "Included => Bar"
    define_singleton_method :foo do
      42
    end
  end
end
class Foo
  include Default
  include Bar
end

p Foo.foo
```

Output of above program

```
Defined => Default
Defined => Bar
Defined => ClassMethods
Included => Default
Included => Bar
42
```